# Does this iptables output mean all traffic is allowed?

Tags: iptables, redhat, linux-networking

I am having problems running a program from a client to my RHEL box that uses a non-standard port and I am trying to track down where the communication problem is occurring.  I'm starting at the server to make sure traffic is being allowed.  Unfortunately I'm no expert at interpreting iptables output.  Here is the command I issued and the output.  Does this mean that ALL traffic on ALL ports is allowed since the policy is "ACCEPT"?

```
# iptables --line-numbers -n -L -v
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 5359 packets, 788K bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 5073 packets, 764K bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

Answer (score 2):

The firewall you show is completely off, and all traffic is being allowed.

Comment: Ah, I was trying to word "Yes" in enough characters and you beat me to it. :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, all traffic is allowed by this configuration.